# What is the correct way to add new object to an Array of Ember Models (ember-model)

Tags: ember.js

I am creating a new Ember.Model with a return response from an ajax call.

This is the ajax method i have in the controller

```
createImageResource: function() {
  var self = this,
      fd = new FormData(),
      newResource = {},
      resources = self.get('controllers.resources.model'),
      fileName = this.get('resource_image').name,
      fileSize = this.get('resource_image').size,
      fileType = this.get('resource_image').type;

  fd.append('resource[resource_type]', 'image');
  fd.append('resource[resource_name]', this.get('resource_name'));
  fd.append('resource[source_id]', this.get('source_id'));
  fd.append('resource_image[resource_image]', this.get('resource_image'));

  fd.append('resource[resource_file_name]', fileName);
  fd.append('resource[resource_file_type]', fileType);
  fd.append('resource[resource_file_size]', fileSize);

  this.set('isProcessingResource', true);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/resources',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: fd,
  }).then(function(newResourceData) {
    newResource = Msmapp.Resource.create(newResourceData.resource);
    resources.pushObject(newResource);
    self.set('isProcessingResource', false);
    self.transitionToRoute('resource', newResource);
  });
},
```

This adds the new resource into the array of objects used by the resources controller. It puts it into the DOM like it should. The issue im having is each object is a link to the individual resource. All of the objects that existed on page load work fine. The object added to the list has the correct url and everything, it just doesnt do anything when you try to navigate.

Im not sure if there is something else i need to do in the .then() ?

This is the template

```
<section class="column_list">
    <ul>
        {{#each resource in controller }}
            <li class="item">
                {{#if resource.isLoading }}
                    {{spinner}}
                {{else}}
                    {{#linkTo 'resource' resource }}
                        <img {{bindAttr src='resource.listAvatar'}} />
                        <div class='title'>{{ resource.resource_name }}</div>
                    {{/linkTo}}
                {{/if}}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding to `resources`, that's what you should be looping over too - `{{#each resource in resources }}`.

Either that or push onto your ArrayController instance directly - `this. resources.pushObject(newResource);`.

Comment: err whoops, fixed my answer